# Convert default column value from datetime to varchar

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have to add a varchar column to a table which defaults to the current timestamp. To do this I somehow need to convert the value from datetime to varchar.

I tried the following

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName`
    CHANGE COLUMN `DocumentID` `DocumentID` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT CONVERT(NOW(), CHAR);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName`
    CHANGE COLUMN `DocumentID` `DocumentID` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT CONVERT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHAR);
```

I always get an error message, that my syntax is wrong. I am using MariaDB and HeidiSQL. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I am basically looking for a MySQL equivalent of the following SQL Server statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TableName_DocumentID]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DocumentID]
```

Comment: Please explain why you would want a date in a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @RickJames I don't :) A service provider of us defined the tables for SQL Server and I have to port it to MariaDB. I don't even know what the field is being used for as I have no insight in their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MariaDB document](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/) says

> In MariaDB 10.2.1 you can use most functions in DEFAULT. Expressions
>   should have parentheses around them.

Hence you may check for the version of MariaDB and use the right syntax (parenthesis around expression):

```
 (CONVERT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHAR))
```

**Update**

As an alternative, you may use [Trigger](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/trigger-examples/) to set the function value for the stable releases (< 10.2)

Comment: I cannot find a version 10.2.1. Only 10.2.0 and that seems to be in alpha state. I am currently using 10.1.14

Comment: As mentioned in the 10.2 release notes https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-1021-release-notes/ `This page describes features in the source repository for MariaDB 10.2. There are currently no official packages or binaries available for download which contain the features. If you want to try out any of the new features described here you will need to get and compile the code yourself.`, you will need to get source and compile for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value, you must use the datatype that the function retrieves, in this case is a timestamp [as you can see in the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/current_timestamp/).

I don't know the reasons that may lead you to save this as a varchar. I'm not sure but I think that MariaDB doesn't allow to call functions as default values so you can't convert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar. You have an alternative approach, make an after insert trigger updating the field (you can call CONVERT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, VARCHAR) inside a trigger).

Either way, I recomend to stay with timestamp.

I see the field is called "DocumentID", perhaps you want to save a hash value as identifier? You can archieve this with [virtual columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/). [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204514/mariadb-virtual-columns-can-i-have-a-hash).

Comment: I have to stay with varchar as the type is defined by an external service provider. Usually an alphanumeric value is entered but for some reason they want to insert the timestamp if no value is passed, whyever their software does that. I'll try the trigger